# Dynamic UIButton controlls and actions in iphone?

Tags: iphone, dynamic, checkbox, uibutton

i am creating an application which includes dynamic pages. actually, i created some dynamic questions and UIButtons (custom checkBox) by checking the responses from the server.
my code is here,

```
  NSString *response=[ResponseFromServer ObjectAtIndex:0];


 if ([comSt compare: @"CheckBoxList"]==NSOrderedSame)
            {

                int count=[ResponseFromServer count];

                            for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
                            {


                                button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
                                button.tag=i;
                                [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 37, 37)];
                                [button setCenter:CGPointMake(116.0,p1)];
                                [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                                [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                                [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                                [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

                                p1=p1+30;
                            }

-(void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
    {

      int tagVal = [(UIButton*)sender tag]; 


         if (tagVal==0) {
              NSLog(@"tag =  0");

             [button setSelected:YES];
             [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];  //not working, button image is not changing 



      }
```

assume i have created 5 dynamic buttons with different tag. i set the image for all those button to uncheck.png first. it works.
but when i clicked a specific button and need to change that button image to checked.png, its not working on the button action.
i need to change it like checkBox control, how will i access the control of a dynamically created button from a group of buttons?

i think u can understand my requirement, thanks in advance..

Comment: You are setting condition for only one button

Comment: yes, i just checked for that button only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding dynamic button set [button setSelected:NO];

Replace method and Add one method given below

```
  -(void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
{

  UIButton *curButton = (UIButton*)sender 

  if (curButton.tag==0) 
  {
     [self buttonAction:curButton];
  }

  if (curButton.tag==1) 
  {
      [self buttonAction:curButton];
  }

  // continues
 }


 -(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)curButton
 {

   if(![curButton isSelected])
     {
       [curButton setSelected:YES];
       [curButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];  //not working, button image is not changing 
     } else {
       [curButton setSelected:NO];
       [curButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     }
 }
```

Comment: i tried this code and also checked with break points, controll goes to this line [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];  successfully but the button image is not changing .

Comment: check edited answer i have edited buttonAction method replace again

Comment: Its not working safecase .., controll reaches, but i dont know what is the problem

Comment: -(void)buttonAction:(UIButton *)curButton
 {

   if(![curButton isSelected])
     {
       [curButton setSelected:YES];
       [curButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];  //not working, button image is not changing 
     } else {
       [curButton setSelected:NO];
       [curButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

     }
 }
Use this method

Comment: omg, itz working noww,,, thankyou so much dear..... thanks for your feedback......

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to change like this

Try this code

```
 if ([comSt compare: @"CheckBoxList"]==NSOrderedSame)
    {
        int count=[ResponseFromServer count];

        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {
            button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            button.tag=0; 
            [button setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 37, 37)];
            [button setCenter:CGPointMake(116.0,p1)];
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.scrollView addSubview:button];

            p1=p1+30;
        }
    }
-(void)checkButtonTapped:(id)sender
    {
        int tagVal = [(UIButton*)sender tag]; 

        if (tagVal==0) {
            NSLog(@"tag =  0");

            [button setSelected:YES];
            [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];   

             [button setTag:100];

             }

             else
             {

                 [button setSelected:YES];
                 [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck.png" forState:UIControlStateSelected];   

                  [button setTag:0];
                  }
 }
```